# Trying to firewall ports 1863, 5190

Tags: firewalls, nmap

I'm using Debian's arno-iptables-firewall and I've configured it to only allow access on the ports I need.

But nmap shows ports 1863, 5190 open. What gives? How can I interrogate those ports further?

As I said, I'm actually using arno-iptables-firewall, but as that is difficult to 'debug' (it is very complex), I'm providing an example of the problem with a very simple demo 'firewall' (without arno), which should do the job, **but apparently isn't**:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 1863 -j DROP 
$ iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:1863 

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Then `nmap example.com -p1863` (from another host) still shows

```
host is up (0.019s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
1863/tcp open  msnp
```

Very confused.

**UPDATE**: OK nmap from different hosts says different things(!). nmap from somewhere else on internet (but within the same VM hosting company's network) shows the ports closed, as they should be, and telnet from these hosts does not work. But from my office ADSL connection, the ports are open and telnet connects (then gets 'closed by foreign host' shortly after).

**CONCLUSION: Having now tested from 6 places on the internet, I can only reproduce this behaviour from my office ADSL. I conclude that it is an issue with local routers or our ISP.** Thank you to everybody who helped me dig deeper into this issue - I learnt a lot!

Comment: Fire up Wireshark and look at the actual traffic. That might help you determine if what you're seeing is a false positive. It might also be useful to use tcpdump on the host you're trying to firewall to see what is happening.

Comment: tcpdump, then telnet to the host on port 1863, shows "3 packets captured, 3 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel". I can't install wireshark as the server is remote, so I'm over ssh only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example it looks like you're trying to config [iptables](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?iptables%208) which is different than [Arno IPTables](http://rocky.eld.leidenuniv.nl/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=45&Itemid=63). Check out this [link for more info on the different types of firewalls](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firewalls).

To see the iptables rules you're running you can type (which you're already doing):

```
iptables -L
```

To block the ports you've listed specifically in iptables, since they're both typically TCP traffic, you can use:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1863 -j REJECT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5190 -j REJECT
```

Warning: Make sure you're leaving your access open before running something like this, but to reject all non-allowed inbound traffic with iptables you would use:

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT
```

The trick with iptables is that you'll need to actually [save the ruleset](http://wiki.debian.org/iptables) since anything that you type via command line is usually flushed on restart.

### Arno's IPTables Firewall

For [Arno IPTables](http://rocky.eld.leidenuniv.nl/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=45&Itemid=63) you can reference the file `/etc/arno-iptables-firewall/firewall.conf` for additional configuration beyond the scope of the debconf dialogs. To start/stop/restart the firewall from the shell, use the command `/etc/init.d/arno-iptables-firewall [start|stop|restart]`

According to the `firewall.conf` file:

> Put in the following variables the TCP/UDP ports you want to DENY(DROP) for
>   everyone (and logged). Also use these variables if you want to log connection
>   attempts to these ports from everyone (also trusted/full access hosts).
>   In principle you don't need these variables, as everything is already blocked
>
> ### (denied) by default, but just exists for consistency.
>
> ```
> DENY_TCP="" DENY_UDP=""
> ```

If Arno IP Tables is running, in theory those ports should already be blocked. Since they appear as though they're not blocked you may only be running [iptables](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?iptables%208).

You can double-check the ports with [`netcat`](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) or try to `telnet` to them to see if it's a false positive from `nmap`.

**Netcat example:**

```
nc -z your_server 1-6000
```

For telnet it if the ports are blocked, they'll say:

```
> telnet your_server 1863
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

If the ports are still open, then you'll see:

```
Connected to your_server
```

This will be followed by the server response.

You should be able to see what's running by typing `top`.

Comment: Thanks, it's the double-check bit I'm not clear on: how would I identify a 'false positive'? Telnet says `Trying 1.2.3.4... Connected to example.com` so looks like it IS open? Is there a way to check Iptables for this port?

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things you can look at for this.

From the host that you're protecting try

`sudo netstat -tunap`

which should show all network connections. Up the top there should be a set of listening TCP ports and the corresponding process which is making use of them.

from the network try

`sudo nmap -sS -sV -sC -v -n [target]`

to see if nmap can figure out any more about the port.

Also in general I notice that you've got the iptables input policy set to ACCEPT.  I'd recommend setting it to DROP and only allowing the ports you need.  It makes securing the box much easier in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. The only relevant info to come from that nmap command is:`1863/tcp open   msnp?` and `5190/tcp open   aol?`. As in, it just added ?s to it. FYI I'm not using the iptables set-up above as my firewall, I'm using arno-iptables-firewall. The set-up in the question was temporary to demonstrate the problem clearly.

Comment: So that indicates that the ports are open but that nmap can't identify the service running on them.  Did netstat -tunap show anything useful?

Comment: I didn't think so, but I'm concerned about `rpc.statd` which is listed as listening on TCP:59061, UDP:40594, UDP:919 as I don't know what that is (or how to kill it)

Comment: @artfulrobot - `rpc.statd` is a reboot notification service used by the NFS file locking service. By default, `rpc.statd` will ask `portmap(8)` to assign it a port number, so this will  vary system to system and is recommended that you assign it a permanent port number when you're configuring a firewall. You can specify that by a call parameter `-p XX` (where _XX_ is a port number). More is [here](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_rpc.statd.htm).

Comment: @TildalWave Thank you. Do I need it running if I'm not being an nfs server (but I am being a client)? I do not normally use nfs, but this particular server comes with some backup space made accessible by an nfs share.

Comment: @artfulrobot - I believe so, and the client instance will _talk_ with the server's lock state through its own instance, but don't take my word for it, I'm not entirely certain this is needed in all cases. It might as well be, that if you're a single client of a NSF share, you don't really need it as there wouldn't be anything to propagate through it - it certainly seems so to me, but as I said, I'm not sure.

Comment: @artfulrobot - On second thought, you'd need it in case the server reboots and you're in the middle of file operation. So  yes, you do need it, unless you're fine without this added protection and can handle failed file operations on client side. Well, this are my thoughts anyway ;)

Comment: @TildalWave thanks. I've found how to fix the port (/etc/default/nfs-common), but in there it says it's not needed by Nfs4. How would I know if I had Nfs4? is there a way to find that out?

Comment: @artfulrobot - `rpcinfo -p | grep nfs` will list all NFS services running, on what port they're running and which version is in use.

Answer (score 2):

A perhaps crude but rather effective way of finding a potential offending application is to use **lsof**.

For example: `lsof -i | grep LISTEN`

Look for services matching the port numbers NMAP claims are open.

Update: Guess I should mention that the command should be run as root to ensure that all open file-handles are listed!

Comment: That returns nothing for these ports.

Comment: Well, it's difficult to make absolute statements but if there are no indications of listening services on those ports it's not entirely unlikely that NMAP is reporting false positives. (Ensure that you run the command as root)

Comment: But why can telnet apparently connect?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to block 1853 and 5190 outbound?  If so Nmap isn't ideally suited to determine firewall rules.  To truly test a firewall rule with near 100% accuracy you need to send traffic THROUGH the firewall to a known destination on the other side, as opposed to trying to scan the firewall interface/IP itself.

From the Nmap docs:

"While Nmap attempts to produce accurate results, keep in mind that all of its insights are based on packets returned by the target machines (or firewalls in front of them). Such hosts may be untrustworthy and send responses intended to confuse or mislead Nmap."   (http://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html)

You need a solution like [IsMyPortBlocked](http://www.ismyportblocked.com) which sends traffic from its client through the firewall and on to the cloud-based server and then back to the client, all over the specified port(s).

Comment: Yeah, basically that's what was happening - my router was intercepting the traffic for some bizarre reason.